# How to get a copy of child entity and save it to another parent using DataNucleus and JDO API?

Tags: jdo, datanucleus

I have a **bidirectional 1 to many relation between SelfEmployed and IncomeExpense** classes. Suppose I have **two different persistent instances of SelfEmployed**. I need to **copy of some SelfExpense object from one parent and add them to another**.

To copy object I just use default constructor to create instance, and then assign only three primitive values, and sets `selfEmployed=null` instance and `id=null`.

BUT, when I do the following `secondSelfEmployed.getIncomeExpenses().add(incomeExpenseCopy);`
Somehow it finds the origin instance of incomeExpense, and sets the rest fields like `id` and `selfEmployed`. Thus, when the transaction commits it `throws the exception`, that I try to add incomeExpense, that already has its parent object selfEmployed

> org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Management of relations : Object "SelfEmployed@6d651cc" has a bidirectional field "incomeExpenses" and the object"IncomeExpense@60942b95" was added to this field, but this field has had its owner set to "SelfEmployed@1fb974bc"!

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class SelfEmployed {

    protected Set<IncomeExpense> incomeExpenses = new HashSet<IncomeExpense>();
    // some primitive fields

    public Set<IncomeExpense> getIncomeExpenses(){
        return incomeExpenses;
    }
    // standard getters and setters
}
```

and

```
    public class IncomeExpense {
        protected int year;
        protected Double annualGrossTurnover;
        protected Double annualExpenses;
        protected SelfEmployed selfEmployed;


        // standard getters and setters 

        public void setSelfEmployed(SelfEmployed selfEmployed) {
            this.selfEmployed = selfEmployed;
        }

        public SelfEmployed getSelfEmployed() {
            return selfEmployed;
        }
}
```

The following logic is performed within transaction.
The problem is here

```
for (IncomeExpense ie: selfEmployed1.getIncomeExpenses()){
    IncomeExpense copy = new IncomeExpense();
    copy.setYear(ie.getYear());
    copy.setAnnualGrossTurnover(ie.getAnnualGrossTurnover());
    copy.setAnnualExpenses(ie.getAnnualExpenses());

    selfEmployed2.getIncomeExpenses().add(copy);// on this line it sets to copy fields id, and selfEmployed, that was in ie
}
```

Comment: why dont you post ACTUAL CODE, and some of the classes? and then consider what lifecycle these objects are in, and make sure you have set BOTH SIDES of a relation.

Comment: where is the "copy.setSelfEmployed()" call? i.e setting BOTH sides of the relation?

Comment: it doesn't work even with copy.setSelfEmployed(), because at that point it gets id of origin instance ie. So even when I set the selfEmployed it fails on commit. Basically, the question is how DataNucleus decide whether this instances exists in cache?

Comment: based on the "id", and the log would tell you when objects come from cache

Comment: But, the copy instance doesn't have an id, before I add it to the Set

Comment: Okay, please tell how you would do this: parent has a Set of child objects. Bidirectional 1 to many. And you want to get one child, create a copy and also add it to the parent. So, you wanna have the same copies with different ids

Comment: If you are ADDING A NEW OBJECT then it will PERSIST it. The log tells you this. Kindly make reference to what the log says

Comment: NO! It does not persist it. It gets the same id, that is in origin.